# SignalR C# Client HubConnection.On method not working

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, console-application

I am trying to implement SignalR using .Net Core Web API (Server side) and Console application (Client Side) to understand the working.

Here is my startup.cs code :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "SignalR", Version = "v1" });
    });
    //Service for SignalR
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddCors(c =>
    {
        c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SignalR v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors(o=>o.AllowAnyOrigin());

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        //Endpoint map for ChatHub, which I've created
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    });
}
```

Here is my ChatHub Class:

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Console application ( Created as SignalR Client):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
       {
           try
           {
               HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:44340/chathub").WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

               await connection.StartAsync();

               if(connection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Connected ... Please type message now");
                   var message = "Hey";
                   //Getting hit to SendMessage method defined in  ChatHub Class
                   await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", message);
                   Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionId);
                   /*
                    Connection.On is not working and unable to writeline on console.
                    I am expecting result Hey on Console.
                    */
                   connection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", m =>
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(m);
                   });
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
       }
```

**I am expecting Result :
ConnectionId 

Hey


But I am getting:
ConnectionId**

Comment: Try sending a message after you configure _On_ message recieve event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `connection.On` register event it too late, the SignalR is broadcast completed on .Net Core Web API. So you can't get the message.

You can move `connection.On` register event before `connection.InvokeAsync` method then you can see the 'Hey' message.

```cs
// ...
// Register event
connection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", m =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(m);
});

if(connection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Connected ... Please type message now");
   var message = "Hey";    
   await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", message);
   Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionId);    
}

// Result:
// Connected ... Please type message now
// Hey
// ConnectionId
```

If you want `ConnectionId` message before `Hey` message, you can change this.

```cs
// ...
// Register event
connection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", m =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(m);
});

if(connection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Connected ... Please type message now");
   var message = "Hey";

   // call async method and wait later
   var task = connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", message);
   Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionId);    

   // wait SendMessage
   await task;
}

// Result:
// Connected ... Please type message now
// ConnectionId
// Hey
```